# quite high enough sentence meaning with one word

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning

> He couldn't  get quite high enough

can anyone explain the **quite high enough** sentence meaning  with one word.
is that meaning of too much high.

Comment: What do you mean by "with one word"? As far as I can tell, you have the meaning backwards. It's not *too much*, it's *not little*

Comment: ***not quite** [adjective] = **almost, close to, nearly** [adjective],* but ***not exactly***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult to explain in a single word, but to understand your example sentence

> He couldn't get **quite high enough**

think of

> He could get **high enough**
>   *He had sufficient height to achieve success*

then the negation

> He ***couldn't*** get high enough
>   *He was to short or low to achieve success*

and

> > He couldn't get ***quite*** high enough
> >     *He was too short by a small amount*